# Remove Duplicates Excel - From Each Day

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet with columns of the following records:

- Caller ID (Customer's number each call came from)
- Date (the dates are when the calls came in since January 1 2017)

How can I efficiently remove duplicate Caller ID's within each day?

If I simply use the Remove Duplicates tool, it will remove duplicates across the entire year so far.

So I pretty much want to remove instances where a customer called more than once in a day.

Here is an example of the data.

[image]

How can I make it so only the first record from each day shows?

My actual sheet has over 100k rows

Comment: If you highlight only the columns you want  and check only those two columns in Remove Duplicates, then it will only look at those two columns and only effect the columns you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Why delete the duplicates?  Just create a pivot table and it can show the unique values and a count of the duplicates.

Comment: In order to see how many calls we received each day and not double coun t callers. For some reason, the crm records multiple records for the same call.

Comment: Perl or Python is really a better solution if you need to do this on a regular basis.  Excel is fine for a quick one time solution but more tedious.  I did find that remove duplicates does work if you filter the list by date first but its a manual intensive approach for 100k records.

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicates tool should work, Are you sure you have only those 2 columns (number and date) ticked in the Remove duplicates tool?

If not, check the date format

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution:

Assuming the data is sorted (ascending) by the date to begin with, you could do a primary sort on date and secondary sort on phone numbers. In an empty column, enter the following formula  `=(b2-b1)+(c2-c1)` (where phone is column b, date is column c and row 2 is your first row of data. Copy and paste to last row of data. Now filter that column for 0 only and then hide or delete those rows.

Now if the data wasn't already sorted by date, and you need it restored to the original order, you could first add a column for a numeric order (i.e. 1,2,3) with formulas. First row (Row 2) of data is a 1, next row is a formula (=a2+1) and copy and paste that to the last row. Now when you run the above process, you would delete the rows with zeroes, then run a final sort on Column A to get back to the original order.

Hope that helps. If this is a one-time thing that should suffice. If not, a macro could do the same thing and shouldn't be too hard to write. Or you could leave the extra columns in place or just hide them, for future use.